# Data Manipulation - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I  want the id1,id2, id3 columns to be transposed to rows keeping the same value for name.

Input:-
[image]

Output:-
[image]

Comment: Post Data as text rather than images @Amy

Comment: Could you add some more details?
What kind of packages do you use,? How do you create the tables (what kind of data types are you using and what is their structure)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,20],[9,11],[7,None],[None,None],['Emma','Elly']]).T
df.columns = ['ID','ID1','ID2','ID3','Name']

data = []
for i,r in df.iterrows():
  r = r.to_dict()
  for k,v in r.items():
    if k.startswith('ID') and v is not None:
      data.append([v,r['Name']])

result = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','Name'])
```

Output:

```
    ID  Name
0   10  Emma
1   9   Emma
2   7   Emma
3   20  Elly
4   11  Elly
```